# List of valid ASCII characters for Objective-C literals and identifiers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm

These variable names below are ALL VALID in Xcode (compiler builds them without a second thought).

```
NSString * ª_name = @"something";
NSString * ø_name = @"something";
NSString * ƒ_name = @"something";
NSString * Ç_name = @"something";
NSString * ç_name = @"something";
NSString * º_name = @"something";
NSString * ı_name = @"something";
NSString * ·name = @"SHIFT+OPTION+9"; // Personal favourite
NSString * π_name = @"something";
NSString * æ_name = @"something";
```

Is there a list somewhere I can see all the valid characters I can use for a variable name?

---

**EDIT:** Many of them still ***fools Xcode indexing*** actually. So better to stick to good'ol underscore. :)

Comment: Whether these characters can be used as identifiers is "implementation defined", that is, the underlying compiler (clang) defines it - not Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C90 allows 63 well known **ASCII** characters in identifiers: Latin upper- and lowercase letters, digits and the underscore.

Since C99 there's the notion of "extended identifiers" which are supported by both clang and gcc in newer versions. [The C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) contains a list of allowed "universal characters" in Annex D. It's a bit long so I only copy the latin range:

> 00AA, 00BA, 00C0−00D6, 00D8−00F6, 00F8−01F5, 01FA−0217, 0250−02A8, 1E00−1E9B, 1EA0−1EF9, 207F

Your favorite "middle dot" (which I like as well) is found in the "Special characters":

> 00B5, 00B7, 02B0−02B8, 02BB, 02BD−02C1, 02D0−02D1, 02E0−02E4, 037A, 0559, 093D, 0B3D, 1FBE, 203F−2040, 2102, 2107, 210A−2113, 2115, 2118−211D, 2124, 2126, 2128, 212A−2131,
>   2133−2138, 2160−2182, 3005−3007, 3021−3029

Comment: @Geri Thanks, I think an iPad version would help most. Yet, I'm afraid there's not enough interest in this kind of niche app to justify the update.

Comment: Hallelujah. Now I'll be able to name my "delta" variables `Δ` and all my colleagues will hate me!

Comment: @Cyrille When they arrive to complain it might be a good opportunity to ask them to do a review of *their* string processing code regarding unicode robustness.

Comment: Many of these character still fools xCode indexing actually. :(

Comment: @Geri See: Most people's string processing is wonky in regard to unicode.

Answer (score 2):

Your source code is actually "implementation defined"

So, when you write

```
NSString * ª_name = @"something";
```

a particular compiler may choke, and it's not portable anymore, nor guaranteed it will work in the next version.

According C11, **§6.4.2 Identifiers**

> 2 An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct. There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.
>
> 3 Each universal character name in an identifier shall designate a character whose encoding in ISO/IEC 10646 falls into one of the ranges specified in D.1.71) The initial character shall not be a universal character name designating a character whose encoding falls into one of the ranges specified in D.2. **An implementation may allow multibyte characters that are not part of the basic source character set to appear in identifiers; which characters and their correspondence to universal character names is implementation-defined.**

(emphasizes mine)

In the GCC documentation, we can read under

> **11.1 Implementation-defined behavior**
>
> - Identifier characters.
>
> The C and C++ standards allow identifiers to be composed of ‘_’ and the alphanumeric characters. C++ and C99 also allow universal character names, and C99 further permits implementation-defined characters. GCC currently only permits universal character names if -fextended-identifiers is used, because the implementation of universal character names in identifiers is experimental. ...

Note that a *Universal character name* is defined as

```
    universal-character-name: \u hex-quad
                              \U hex-quad hex-quad
```

Comment: Your post suggests you're in opposition of unicode identifiers (and I partly agree on this opinion). Yet, I don't agree with your reasoning: Everybody uses unicode in string literals (and Apple recommends it as well) even though it's the same paragraph in the C standard that describes this feature. And there's more implementation defined concepts we rely upon each day, like support for floating point types. To me the best argument *against* unicode identifiers is: Nobody uses them, so other developers will stumble upon your code and might be confused. Code should be as readable as possible.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe In Objective-C one can use Unicode string literals as `NSStrings`, e.g. `@"µs".` In C99, C11 using unicode characters in string literals is "implementation defined", and I wouldn't encourage to use it. An option would be to use C++11 new unicode string literals. So, we _have_ Unicode string literals in Objective-C and C++11 - and I'm not in opposition to use it. For identifiers though, it's "implementation defined", and thus I wouldn't recommend to use it, for several reasons. ;)