# Using "?" in variable name for Objective-C development

Tags: objective-c

I wanted to create a variable called `emailValid?` in Xcode but the compiler is giving me the error `Expected ';' at end of declaration`. It seems like it is expecting the ternary operator. Can it be done or does anyone know a good alternative?

Thanks

Comment: `?` is not valid in a variable name.  Normally you'd name it something like `emailIsValid` or `isEmailValid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` is not a valid character for variable, class, or method names (or any other names for that matter).

Please see the following question for more details on the valid characters that can be used for identifiers: [List of valid ASCII characters for Objective-C literals and identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827102/list-of-valid-ascii-characters-for-objective-c-literals-and-identifiers)